# Making a if statment the value of a variable in php

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

Ive got an if statment which im using in php as part of a foreach loop.

What id like to do is make the if statement a variable so that i could just call the variable. Somthing like this

```
$best_xml = if ($wh_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'] < $lad_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal']) {
    $lad_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'];
  }

  else {
    $wh_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'];
  };
```

But i keep getting this error when i run it -  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/event.php on line 74 (line 74 is the first line starting $best_xml)

Is this possible / is this the right way to do it ?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to save the conditional value in the `if` statement parenthesis to the variable `best_xml` or are you trying to save one of the two response values `$lad_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'];` or `$wh_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'];` to the variable `best_xml`?

Comment: im trying to save the response values

Comment: Got ya. Then the answers below should work. Sorry I was just a little confused on what we were trying to save here. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if` statements don't evaluate to an assignable value in PHP. You can't assign an if statement to a variable.

You can, however, use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
$best_xml = $wh_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'] < $lad_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'] ? 
  $lad_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'] : $wh_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'];
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$best_xml = ($wh_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'] < $lad_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal']) ? $lad_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal']:$wh_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'];
```

`$best_xml` will then hold the value of either `$lad_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal']` (if true), or `$wh_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal']` (if false).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that, but you can use this:

```
$best_xml = ($wh_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'] < $lad_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal']) ? $lad_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'] : $wh_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact you *can* do this with these neat new things called "functions". Yours should look like:

```
function myFunction($var1, $var2) {
    if ($var1 < $var2) {
        return $var1;
    } else {
        return $var2;
    }
}

$best_xml = myFunction($wh_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'], $lad_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal']);
```

Answer (score 0):

`if` doesn't return value, you have to assign value *manually*:

```
$best_xml = null;
if ($wh_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'] < $lad_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal']) {
    $best_xml = $lad_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'];
} else {
    $best_xml = $wh_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'];
};
```

or you can use ternary operator:

```
$best_xml = $wh_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'] < $lad_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'] ? 
            $lad_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'] : $wh_odds_attrib['oddsDecimal'];
```